# Selecting text while contenteditable=true will copy text of nodes with style user-select=none;

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

Got a problem. When you open the Fiddle you will see a contenteditable page. Some nodes have the style user-select=none, and when you press ctrl-a to select all you will see all content is selected without those of style user-select:none

But if you copy the selected text with ctrl-c and open notepad and paste it, all text with user-select=none is inserted there.

[JS Fiddle](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMIV5WK10KPD)

Comment: Update: runit in chrome. Firefox is ignoring moz-user-select (?) in that case?

Comment: `user-select` does not prevent copy and paste. You may find this helpful -- https://danoc.me/blog/css-prevent-copy/

Comment: Thanks, but it might be a bad thing not being able to prevent copying non copyable contents. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running well with **Firefox** but It didn't run correctly with **Chrome**, **Opera**, **Safari**.

I think **user-select** property with value **none** has some bugs with some browsers.

Try this sample code across different browsers and you will know.

```css
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```

```html
<p>Selectable text1.</p>
<p class="noselect">Unselectable text1.</p>
<p>Selectable text2.</p>
<p class="noselect">Unselectable text2.</p>
```